# Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'- Error in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, nopcommerce

I have read all related questions and no solutions worked for me. Among them, things that I tried were:

1. Rebuild and published in Release mode with Any CPU platform. I also tried rebuilding and publishing with x64.
2. Reinstalled .Net 4.5.1
3. Made sure I'm referencing the correct "bit" version. Not only this but I also tried uploading to our Azure site the DLLs from this folder: *{Windows dir}\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319*. That is the folder where .Net 4.5.1 was installed - validated in registry (regedit).
4. Checked and verified that our Azure website is in 64-bit mode
5. Verified that the target framework in VS is .Net Framework 4.5.1 - I'm using VS 2013

Our site is built with nopcommerce v3.3. I'm thinking that the issue is not caused by the nopcommerce project. The site runs on my local machine. I also researched on Azure support for .net 4.5.1 and found [this page](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-sites/suggestions/5400513-support-for-net-4-5-1) stating that Azure supports 4.5.1 since March.

With all those information what else could I be missing? Thanks in advance.

By the way here's the exception details:

> Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll' or one of its
>   dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

I've researched on that too (BadImageFormatException) and the suggestion was to build with "Any CPU" that I already did. My local machine is running on Windows 7 SP1 64-bit from which the project was built - not sure if this is related to the problem.